# Count duplicates in SQL and partition by specific column

Tags: sql, presto

I am trying to count all duplicate values for the column `listing_id`  for a given seller_id and group this by a region where the seller is based.

The fields are: `region_id`, `seller_id` and `listing_id`

I would like to return the following table output:

```
Region_id     seller_id    listing_id   count_duplicates

1335          45353        73535        1
4422          33566        67343        4
4334          64646        73255        5
3433          45466        37464        2
```

My query only returns the count for the number if listings for a given seller_id

```
SELECT region_id, seller_id, listing_id,
       count(listing_id) OVER PARTITION BY seller_id) AS count_duplicates
FROM table
```

Comment: provide your table schema.

Comment: Sample data corresponding to your results would help.  You should also define what *you* mean by "duplicates".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

select region_id, seller_id, listing_id, count(*)
from table

group by region_id, seller_id ,listing_id
having count(*)>1